# List of tab delimited arrays to numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Win 7, x64, Python 2.7.12

I have data in the form

```
myData = [[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1, g1, h1], [a2, b2, c2, .... ], ..... ]
```

where `myData` is a `np.ndarray` of floats. I saved this by using the following...

```
with open('myData.txt', 'w') as f:
    for s in myData:
        f.write(str(s) + '\n')
```

Which on inspection was actually saved like...

```
[a1   b1   c1   d1   e1   f1   g1   h1]
[a2   b2   c2   d2   e2   f2   g2   h1]
.....
```

i.e. tab delimited.

So I tried to read it back in using...

```
import numpy as np
from ast import literal_eval

with open('myData.txt', 'r') as f:
    fromFile = [np.ndarray(literal_eval(line)) for line in f]
f.close()
```

But this throws an error...

```
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [ 1.     1.198  2.063  1.833  1.458  1.885  1.969  0.343]
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So given that I cant regenerate the file `myData.txt` how do restore it to its initial data type?

Also is there a way of stopping the data being written out like that in the first place?

EDIT: A solution to the above...

```
import numpy as np
from ast import literal_eval

branches = ['[ 1.     1.198  2.063  1.833  1.458  1.885  1.969  0.343]\n', 
            '[ 2.    1.26  2.    1.26  1.26  2.    1.26  0.  ]\n', 
            '[ 3.     1.688  2.     1.781  1.573  2.021  1.979  0.23 ]\n', 
            '[ 4.     1.604  2.729  1.792  1.667  2.49   1.948  0.293]\n']

branches = [line.rstrip(']\n') for line in branches]
branches = [line.lstrip('[ ') for line in branches]
print branches[0]

branches = [line.split('  ') for line in branches]
newBranches = []
for branch in branches:
    branch = filter(None, branch)
    branch = [float(item) for item in branch]
    newBranches.append(branch)

print newBranches[0]

branches = np.array(newBranches)
```

Unless there is a faster way of doing this then thats how I'll be doing it. I will also be taking Nils Werner's advice below in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
numpy.save('myData.npy', myData)
```

which you can then read like

```
myData = numpy.load('myData.npy')
```